RequestRejectedException starting logging in influxdb with spring-boot-actuator 2.7.18 version
After Upgrading spring boot version from 2.0.5.RELEASE to 2.7.18 in my application, now the RequestRejectedExceptions started logging in influxdb. With older version , it didn't log but with the new version it start logging.
